# guflow error ACTIVITY_ID_ALREADY_IN_USE aws

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

Hi in my api I receive 2 patch that send the signal to schedule the same activity, this is because receive diferent content , but when I tried to made this I receive the exeption ACTIVITY_ID_ALREADY_IN_USE and the workflow in aws go to failed status, you know how I cna schedule both activities at the same tiem or if I can schedule on after the other when is one is active, I use guflow  to create workflow and schedule activities

Answer (score 0):

I believe error indicates not the activity type, but activity ID is in use. Make sure that you use a different ID when scheduling the second activity.